# I want to give an event to drawn picture

Tags: wxpython

I want to give an event to my drawn picture.

Currently, I draw the rectangle with wxPython,

and I want to connect link like button.

Is it possible?

If it possible please advice to me.

Below is the my code.

```
import wx

class Example(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, title):
        super(Example, self).__init__(parent, title=title, 
            size=(350, 280))

        self.Bind(wx.EVT_PAINT, self.OnPaint)

        self.Centre()
        self.Show()


    def OnPaint(self, e):
        dc = wx.ClientDC(self)

        dc.SetBrush(wx.Brush("YELLOW"))
        self.original = dc.DrawRectangle(10, 15, 90, 60)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App()
    Example(None, 'Colours')
    app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 0):

When you first look at this, it will be tempting to call your OnPaint method when a button is pressed.   But this will not work the way you want it do.

An important point about drawing stuff is that you need your OnPaint event handler to be called every time the screen needs to be re-drawn - obviously.   This means that you need the logic for what should be drawn to be availble to it at all times, so it can be called as often as you like.   You can not draw something once on a button press and expect it to stay drawn - the next paint event will wipe it out.

This means you need logic like this:

```
import wx

class Example(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, title):
        super(Example, self).__init__(parent, title=title, 
            size=(350, 280))

        self._showRectangle = False

        draw_button = wx.Button(self, label="Press Me")

        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnButtonPressed, draw_button)

        self.Bind(wx.EVT_PAINT, self.OnPaint)

        self.Centre()
        self.Show()

    def OnButtonPressed(self, e):
        self._showRectangle = not(self._showRectangle)

    def OnPaint(self, e):
        # This must be called from EVT_PAINT, not EVT_BUTTON
        print "painting..."
        if self._showRectangle:
            dc = wx.ClientDC(self)

            dc.SetBrush(wx.Brush("YELLOW"))
            self.original = dc.DrawRectangle(10, 15, 90, 60)


app = wx.App()
Example(None, 'Colours')
app.MainLoop()
```

I put a print statement in there to emphasise the need to understand when this handler gets called.   Experiment with minimising and maximizing the app, etc...

HTH

Answer (score 0):

Note:

You do not want to use a ClientDC inside a paint event! You use a PaintDC instead.

A Paint even occurs whenever the system needs to re-paint teh window. So what you want o do is:

- store the state of the window in your class.
- In the paint handler, construct a PaintDC, and use the state of teh object to draw what you want the Window to look like.
- If you want the look of the Window to update due to some other event than a system Paint event, then call:
  self.Refresh()
  self.Update()

That will trigger a paint event.

(you could also use  ClientDC and draw, but it's beter to use Update() -- that will let the system time the drawing better)

There is a lot about drawing on the Wiki herre:

http://wiki.wxpython.org/RecipesImagesAndGraphics

I haven't answered your question about the lining with a button because I don't understand what you want to do. But look for the Mouse events -- that may be what you want.